# Why version of SBT is playing role in name of fully qualified dependency?

Tags: scala, sbt

Why version of SBT is playing role in name of fully qualified dependency ?

I thought it only depends on version of Scala.

Here is example.

- `build.sbt` has `scalaVersion` set to `2.10.2`
- `build.properties` has `sbt.version` set to `0.12.1`
- `plugins.sbt` has plugin dependency `"com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.12.0-0.2.11.1"`

If I build it I see following in the log:

```
[info] Resolving com.github.siasia#xsbt-web-plugin_2.9.2;0.12.0-0.2.11.1 ...
```

But if I change `sbt.version` set to `0.13.0-RC5` SBT fails to find this plugin and says in the log

```
[info] Resolving com.github.siasia#xsbt-web-plugin_2.10;0.12.0-0.2.11.1 ...
```

Why did it change scala version if it remains 2.10.2 in my config ? How to fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sbt projects are recursive, so each layer has its own settings(including scala version and classpath) (see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html )

sbt plugins are just regular libraries which depend on sbt, hence the plugins need to be cross-built across sbt versions (and each sbt version may require different scala version)

addSbtPlugin function takes care of that and resolves an appropriate artifact for current sbt and scala

siasia#xsbt-web-plugin is not really maintained anymore and it does not have versions for sbt 0.13, use https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/xsbt-web-plugin as a replacement